# Why debugfs is mounted on /sys/kernel/debug?

Tags: filesystems, sysfs, debugfs

As far as I know, `/sys/` is for sysfs, why debugfs is mounted under the `/sys/` directory? Why not just mount it under `/debug/` to make it clearer?

Comment: Welcome to Unix! It is best to not put multiple questions in a single question.

Comment: @JamesRisner Thanks, edited.

Answer (score 1):

To keep things clean and avoid spreading information into another root subdirectory.

`/sys` is an interface to the kernel, so it makes sense that debugfs (which is a RAM-based filesystem designed for debugging purposes) is placed in a subdirectory of `/sys` i.e. `/sys/kernel/debug`.

Comment: Another question is, why can these 2 mount points be overlapped?